# How to use lambda to erase empty vector cells?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a vector:

```
std::vector<Edge> edges(num);
```

which contain empty cells at the end, which I would like to remove using lambda but when I did:

```
edges.erase(std::remove_if(edges.begin(), edges.end(), 
                       std::mem_fn(&std::Edge::empty), edges.end() );
```

I got this error:

```
error C2664: 'bool main::<lambda_6f33349b59d49f69703a5fa6a8c5995a>::operator ()(const std::vector<_Ty> &) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Edge' to 'const std::vector<_Ty> &'
```

What do I do now?

Comment: I don't think there is `std::Edge::empty` function available in std.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to use lambda to erase empty vector cells?

You just need to provide a simple lambda that returns true if an `Edge` is empty:

```
edges.erase(std::remove_if(edges.begin(), 
                           edges.end(), 
                           [](const Edge& e){return e.empty();}), 
            edges.end() );
```

This assumes `Edge` has a suitable member function `empty()`:

```
class Edge
{
 public:

  bool empty() const { .... }

  // as before
};
```

Comment: I tried the code above and my compiles says 'error C2039 empty is not a member of Edge'

Comment: @Napalidon well, I guessed from your original code that `Edge` had an `empty` method, since you seemed to be attempting to call it. What method tells you if an `Edge` is empty?

Comment: I don't have one. How do I write it? just check if all instance variables are 0?  And I just return true? or can I inherit it?

Comment: @Napalidon  If you can't know than an `Edge` is empty, then you can't remove empty `Edges`. And if you can't know whether they are empty, it should make no difference if they are. You have to figure out what you mean by "empty", then provide a means for testing for it.

Comment: `Edge` is your own defined class is it not? Just write an `empty` method that checks it meets your criteria for being 'empty'.

Comment: I tried and I got: Edge::empty' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Edge' to 'Edge &'  All I want to do is remove those elements that were not set with values. Is there and easier way to do this?

Comment: @Napalidon you need to make is a `const` member: `class Empty { public: bool empty() const { .... } };`. Checking an `Edge` for emptiness should not modify it, so the method should be `const`.

Comment: Great, finally made it work. Thank ya'll, especially juanchopanza :)